# How to get data from mySQL to UITextView?

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode, phpmyadmin, uitextview

I studied this tutorial:
[Iphone Connect to mysql database](http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/)

Everything works fine. I can create tables on php myAdmin and can show them in a table view in an app in the Simulator. 
But since yesterday I'm searching for help, because I don't know how to get a data from mySQL and show it on a simple UITextView. Can you make me an example or do you know a tutorial? 
Thanks for answers.

Comment: I mean the data in my sql is shown on my iOS simulator (Table View). Just as in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As I've skimmed through the tutorial, your UITableViewCell should have line of code that looks like this:

```
myCell.textLabel.text = item.address;
```

The `item.address` contains the text that you want to be displayed in your cell, so the same thing to your `UITextView`

```
//                                                                      x, y, width,height
UITextView *newTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300,25)];
[newTextView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
newTextView.text = item.address;
newTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

[self.view addSubview:newTextView];
```

Comment: Hey thanks. But there is a method: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Retrieve cell
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    
    // Get the location to be shown
    Location *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
    
    // Get references to labels of cell
    myCell.textLabel.text = item.address;
    
    return myCell;
}` How can I get `indexpath.row` in another method?

Comment: @Mehmet63 Please accept the answer if it helped. And check this answer to get the index path.row in another method http://stackoverflow.com/a/7452428/2053537

Comment: Because I want to show only the UITextView and not the UITableView.

Comment: @Mehmet63 it is a lot better to add additional information to the regional question and there is formatting to make the code readable.

Comment: The regional question is: How can I get a data from the mysql table and show it in the UITextView?